# Is there any way to send audio to small speaker which is used in calls in android?

Tags: java, android

Have searched for hours on google and still wondring is there a way sending audio to the small speaker in devices , Means to the speaker which is used as an incoming call audio otuput.

any link or resource would be helpful.

Here is how i am accessing the mic audio of a device

```
 AudioRecord read= new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 8000, 
 AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,      
 AudioFormat.ENCODING_DEFAULT,AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, 
 AudioFormat.ENCODING_DEFAULT));
```

Now i want to send this audio to device call incoming speaker :( or whatever it is called .

Answer (score 2):

Yup you can use

> ```
> AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, SAMPLE_RATE,
>                         AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, BUF_SIZE,
>                         AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
>                 track.play();
> ```

The `AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL` makes the system route the call through the small speaker used in calls.

Comment: Thanks It seems helpful :) but i wan to play this to call incoming speaker (The small speaker close to ear used while talking ) rather thatn the big speaker . . so will this code do the trick or i need to add something else ??

Comment: Ya i have built peer to peer calling app using this code and it works..the sound is played in small speaker near to ear..

Comment: :D :D i was working on same. . :D can you give me  link of the app ??

Comment: could you please explain your answer more?